Magento 2.4.7 Media Gallery to upload webp image not show in manage Gallery
We use the Webp Support extension, when we upload, the Webp image is successfully uploaded but not showing in manage Gallary in the admin backend.
Please see given below Screenshot.

https://i.imgur.com/qFPtV1v.png
https://i.imgur.com/RFPOm52.png
we have used a preference for this file "Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage".
It's working for the old Magento Media Gallery.
https://i.imgur.com/uTPDYhK.png

any idea for this problem so please reply.
Thank you.

If webp images are not appearing in the Magento 2.4.7 Media Gallery, ensure the following:
WebP Support: Magento 2.4.7 supports WebP, but server-side PHP GD or ImageMagick must be enabled to handle WebP images.
Image Upload Process: Verify that the image is properly uploaded and meets Magento's media requirements.
Cache Management: Clear the Magento cache after uploading (bin/magento cache:clean).
Media Permissions: Check folder permissions in pub/media. Ensure correct read/write access.
Media Synchronization: Run bin/magento media-gallery:sync to update the gallery.
If the issue persists, inspect logs in var/log/ for errors.
